# Add to json list in Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I am very new to Node and I am saving my data in a json file, and I want to dynamically add people to a json list. How would I go about this?

JSON:

```
{
  "people": []
}
```

JavaScript

```
const fs = require('fs');

function addPerson() {
  var jsonFile = fs.readFileSync("/Users/Nick/Desktop/Js/names.js");
  var content = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
  var newPerson = {
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Davis",
    "job": "developer"
  };
  content.people.push(newPerson);
}

addPerson()
```

Error

```
undefined:1
const fs = require('fs');
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: FYI, in node.js `require('somefile.json')` will read the JSON and parse it synchronously for you in one step.  The key is that it has the `.json` file extension.

Comment: You are getting an error because `fs.readFileSync("/Users/Nick/Desktop/Js/names.js")` is the path to your JS file and not your JSON file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays have `.push`.

```
var obj = {
  "people": []
};

obj.people.push(yourPersonObj);
```

If it's a JSON string, use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to parse the Json string to an object, then add the required data to the array, them stringify the object back to json.

```
var obj = {
  "people": []
};
JSON.parse(obj);
obj.people.push (yourNewData);
JSON.stringify (obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file asynchronously and parse the data. You can then simply push the new JSON object to the array before writing the updated data back to the file.

```
var fs = require('fs')

var newPerson = {
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Davis",
    "job": "Developer"
};

fs.readFile('./people.json', function(err, data) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    var content = JSON.parse(data);
    content.people.push(newPerson);
    fs.writeFile('./people.json', JSON.stringify(content), function(err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log('Done!')
    });
});
```

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json to read huge json files that exceed the available memory.